# A better way to do git clone

Tags: git, shell, automation

This is lazy programmer request. I would like to create a shell script automate the following process:

```
git clone <remote-repo-url>
cd <cloned-folder>
open <cloned-folder>
```

So the idea here is to clone a URL and then immediately `cd` into the `cloned-folder`. The trick here is to identify the `cloned-folder` from the url pattern.

For now we can assume that url structure is in this pattern `.../<cloned-folder>.git` i.e. the url.

I am wondering if we can actually do with using `awk` or some tools like that. The part i am stuck is finding a appropriate `regex`, I guess.

**USE CASE**: Here the use case is if you clone a url, you want to be in the repofolder as soon as possible. The is the pre-requirement if you want to run any `git` command like `git log` or `mate .` which we do 99% of the time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

bash function to do this (works in zsh also):

```
function lazyclone {
    url=$1;
    reponame=$(echo $url | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/.git$//');
    git clone $url $reponame;
    cd $reponame;
}
```

The `awk` command prints the part after the last `/` (e.g from `http://example.com/myrepo.git` to `myrepo.git`). The `sed` command removes the trailing `.git`

Usage:

```
$ pwd
~/
$ lazyclone https://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api.git
tvdb_api
Cloning into 'tvdb_api'...
remote: Counting objects: 1477, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (534/534), done.
remote: Total 1477 (delta 952), reused 1462 (delta 940)
Receiving objects: 100% (1477/1477), 268.48 KiB | 202 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (952/952), done.
$ pwd
~/tvdb_api
```

Comment: The provided answer does not handle repositories whose humanish names are located before the trailing slash. Neither does it handle `git-bundle` repositories. I suggest whoever is interested in supporting these two edge cases to use the (old) official Git shell script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840631/1248449

Answer (score 2):

With git clone, you can specify the folder to clone to, instead of allowing it to be named automatically.

```
dir=myclone
git clone git://somerepo "$dir"
cd "$dir"
open "$dir"
```

Comment: yes i can do that... but i want my folder name to be extracted from the url itself.

Comment: i want to create a shortcut for git clone <url> with added functionality

Answer (score 1):

An improvement from @dbr's answer:

```
function lazyclone {
    reponame=${1##*/}
    reponame=${reponame%.git}
    git clone "$1" "$reponame";
    cd "$reponame";
}
```

With the help of Bash's parameter expansion, we can get rid of `awk` and `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

The bash parameter version is quite nice, I went with `basename` cuz it seemed cleaner

```
function gclocd {
  # git clone and enter the cloned file
  if [[ -z "$2" ]]; then
    reponame=$(basename "$1" ".git");
  else
    reponame=$2;
  fi
    git clone "$1" "$reponame";
  cd "$reponame";
}
```

I use short memorable tab-completable function names for a bunch of things like this and put them in my `.bashrc` as aliases/functions, e.g. `gcmmt` for `git commit -m`. `lazy` may well already be a prefix for things in your shell, which means it's that little bit more to type each time...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting directory name from url, we could just `cd` into the latest created directory. Here is the corresponding shell script:

```
gclcd() {
    git clone --recursive $* && cd "$(ls -t | head -1)"
}
```