# How to determine the "humanish" part of a git repository

Tags: git, scripting

If I clone a git repository like this

```
git clone <some-repository>
```

git creates a directory, named as the 'humanish' part of the source repository. (according to the man page).

Now I want to create a bash script that clones a repository, 'cds' into the newly created directory, and does some stuff. Is there an easy way for the bash script to know the name of the created directory, without explicitly providing a directory to the 'git clone' command?

Answer (score 5):

To add to Hiery's answer, you will find a complete shell script example in the git repo itself:
[`contrib/examples/git-clone.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/examples/git-clone.sh), with the [relevant extract](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/examples/git-clone.sh#L218-L234):

```
# Decide the directory name of the new repository
if test -n "$2"
then
    dir="$2"
    test $# = 2 || die "excess parameter to git-clone"
else
    # Derive one from the repository name
    # Try using "humanish" part of source repo if user didn't specify one
    if test -f "$repo"
    then
        # Cloning from a bundle
        dir=$(echo "$repo" | sed -e 's|/*\.bundle$||' -e 's|.*/||g')
    else
        dir=$(echo "$repo" |
            sed -e 's|/$||' -e 's|:*/*\.git$||' -e 's|.*[/:]||g')
    fi
fi
```

Note that it takes into account cloning a **[bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)** (which is a repo as *one* file, useful when working with a [repository in the cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632723/git-with-dropbox/3633346#3633346)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the url and parse it to get the latest part and strip off the .git.

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$1

# Strip off everything from the beginning up to and including the last slash
REPO_DIR=${URL##*/}
# Strip off the .git part from the end of the REPO_DIR
REPO_DIR=${REPO_DIR%%.git}

git clone $URL
cd $REPO_DIR
....
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar: 

    `echo $giturl|sed 's/.*[:/]\([^:/]*\)\.git$/\1/'`