# How to do a git clone and enter the created directory

Tags: git, powershell

How to `git clone` a project and then `cd` into the newly created directory in one action?

```
git clone http//xxx (optional folder name)
cd <created directory>
```

I found several solutions in Bash, like this one:
[A better way to do git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058705/a-better-way-to-do-git-clone)

But none in PowerShell..

Comment: Do you really clone so many times a day that it's worth our time to post this question?

Comment: I guess it depends on where you want to stop being more efficient. Even if you only do it once a week, why not improve the workflow. A next step to this script could be to check if there is a package.json and if so also do an npm install & npm start. So you clone a repository and go get a coffee while it does its work instead of waiting at the commandline for the previous command to finish.

Comment: If you're not cloning nine repos before breakfast, what are you really doing in life?

Answer (score 5):

It really isn't very complicated to turn your referenced `bash` solution into PowerShell:

```
function Invoke-GitClone($url) {
  $name = $url.Split('/')[-1].Replace('.git', '')
  & git clone $url $name | Out-Null
  Set-Location $name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm doing some research again and am cloning lots of repositories.

The following snippet supports passing a custom directory name like `git clone` also does which Ansgar Wiechers' answer did not take into account.

```
function Invoke-GitClone($url, $name) {
    if (!$name) {
        $name = $url.Split('/')[-1].Replace('.git', '')
    }
    & git clone $url $name | Out-Null
    Push-Location $name
}

Set-Alias gitclone Invoke-GitClone
```

I never got around posting a full solution because this still doesn't support passing flags like `--recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner for true git and PowerShell aficionados:

```
(git clone https://github.com/BLAH/BLUH.git 2>&1) -replace ".+'([^']+)'.+",'$1' | Set-Location
```

Why does this work? We use [output stream redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection). See the [git manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITREDIRECTSTDOUTcode) for more info.