# How do I git clone and CD into the folder I just made in one line?

Tags: git

On my course, very often we git clone and then cd into the folder we just made. 
We've got hundreds of repositories and so it would have saved/ continue to save a lot of time. Especially when the things we are cloning have similar names.

I have tried googling the problem and tried appending some things onto the git clone 'repo here' line.

For example i'm in a folder called week 4, what I currently do is copy a repo lets say 'advanced-JS', then gcl advanced-JS, then cd advanced-JS.
But what id like to do it type gcl advanced-JS (x), for it to clone it onto my computer and cd into the folder it just made. x being the unknown here.

Thank you.

Comment: Write a shell script in your shell of choice

Comment: did you try `git clone repo-url && cd repo-folder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been described here (and similar places):

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/how-to-cd-automatically-after-git-clone
- [How to do a git clone and enter the created directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539250/how-to-do-a-git-clone-and-enter-the-created-directory)

you can create a shell function:

```
gclonecd() {
   git clone "$1" && cd "$(basename "$1" .git)"
}
```